# help with jQuery selector to find last DIV in the body that doesn't have fixed positioning

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, position, fixed

I am fighting this thing and cannot figure it out... can someone please help.

I want to find the last DIV in the BODY that:
   A) Is NOT a specified ID (the easy part); and
   B) Does NOT have fixed positioning (the part that's killing me)

Basically, I am looking for the last DIV in the BODY that's part of the flow, so I can add a bit of margin-bottom.

this is where I am at so far:

```
$(theBody).children('div').not('#toolbar').not(':fixed').find(':last');

$.expr[':'].fixed = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    if ($(obj).css('position')=='fixed') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

it's not working, and I think the custom selector is overthinking it.... I just dunno how to work it in there.

Thanks in advance, folks!

Comment: BTW, the "theBody" selector I started with is just a variable I am using to cache $('body')

Comment: children only find immediate children (one level down). Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is define the custom selector above the code where you use it :)

The selector I believe you want is...

```
$('body > div:fixed:not(#toolbar):last')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUt5U/).

I also provided a terser custom selector...

```
$.expr[':'].fixed = function(obj){
   return $(obj).css('position') == 'fixed';
};
```

Comment: Thanks... before I test this one, it looks *at a glance* like this finds the last fixed div, I am specifically looking for a not-fixed div.  would that then become:

$('body > div:not(:fixed):not(#toolbar):last')

Comment: OK, I checked, and yes, the selector needs to be tweaked as mentioned in my prev. comment to specify the last DIV that is *not* fixed.  Thanks for your help!!!